# How to log daily activity in SQL

Tags: sql, database

I want to keep track of certain things on my site that happen throughout the day, and then I want to be able to compile the data so that I can view it on a day to day basis. What is the best way to do this in a SQL database? Would there be a better method than keeping "date|action|data" for each time (could be thousands per day) something happens, and then when I want to look at it just pull "where date = X"? Seems like this will have a lot of overhead, but I'm not sure how else to do it.

Comment: What database is this? If you're using Oracle, for instance, you could use [Oracle Grid Control](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/oem/grid-control/overview/index.html) (part of Oracle Enterprise Manager) to monitor activity

Comment: its a SQL database, and monitoring different activities by different users on my site

Comment: What information are you logging in your database?  Web visits/activity - or SQL activity?

Comment: web activity, keeping track of what users do on the site

Comment: This question is very broad. Asking "what is the best way" is subjective, and you're not making it clear what you have tried or what problems you have faced during your attempt of implementing this. "Seems like" is not a very precise measurement either. Test *something*, and use a profiler to check if it actually is cpu or memory heavy.

Answer (score 0):

MySql may not be suited for storing large amounts of log data but with some optimizations it can get better here are some tips:

- Use MyISAM with concurrent inserts
- Rotate tables daily and use union to query
- Use delayed inserts with MySQL or a job processing agent like Gearman

The retrieval of data may not be a problem here but the storage engine matters a lot and MySAM is your best option in this case given that there are not transactions(which it doesn't support).

The maximum number of rows supported for MyISAM is ~4.29E+09 with up to 64 indexs per table. Which I think is pretty good for you.

Check out this detailed article regarding efficient [Logging with MySql](http://brian.moonspot.net/logging-with-mysql)